# Django: Question on Template Inheritance

Tags: python, html, django, templates

Hello I seem to be having a problem of using a base template. My base html is called  help_content.html.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="CONTENT-TYPE" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <a href="help_new_client.html">New Client</a>
    <title>User Manual</title>
    <style></style></head>
<body style="padding:10px;">
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my child template named help_new_client.html

```
{% extends "help_content.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h3 class="western">New  Client</h3>
<p><b>Add client</b></p>
<p>If you are not already on the All clients screen then click “VIEW
CLIENTS” on the main menu.</p>
<p>Click on the Add client button. A Client form is displayed. Fill
the form and click save.</p>
<p>Action: VIEW CLIENTS → Add client → save</p>
<p><b>Edit client</b></p>
<p>To edit a  client simply click on the client in the All clients
list. Edit the clients information and save.</p>
<p>Action: VIEW CLIENT → click on client → click on Edit client
information → save 
</p>

{% endblock %}
```

**EDIT: views**

```
@login_required
def help_index(request):
    return render_to_response('help_content.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))

@login_required
def help_new_client(request):
    return render_to_response('help_new_client.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I am not really sure what I have done wrong. In help_content.html, I see `{% block content %}{% endblock %}` and in help_new_client.html, I see `{% extends "help_content.html" %}` `{% block content %}` `{% endblock %}`. I'm not sure why I am receiving these template tags rather than my content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you are not rendering the template from a view.

Are you sure you are doing something like this in a view, and that you are executing that view via a corresponding url pattern:

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('help_content.html',
                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I don't see in your extended template this as the first line:

```
{% extends 'help_content.html' %}
```

And close the `</body>` tag in your base template just to be sure.

Comment: For some reason that still did not work. I created a view for both base and child template and put their link in the urls.py file. So still does the same as before.

Comment: I've got `{% extends "help_content.html" %}` in my template. I have remove edited the body tag but still there is a problem.

Comment: @Shehzad009 And are you really sure that Django is parsing the templates and it's not the server returning the file it finds

Comment: Ok I think I may have done it. Initially help_new_client.html and help_content.html were both in my media directory. I have moved them both to the main templates directory - and tweaked their url paths.

Answer (score 0):

i have my base template in the template folder. And I have sub folders for all my other templates.

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response;
def help_index(request):
    return render_to_response('html-template/help_new_client.html')
```

in your case it would be

```
return render_to_response('help_new_client.html')
```